# Map + Legend on same svg

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I've been trying for a week now to realize this [Map+Legend](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SkEQjiAk0GaagmfcIw1?p=preview)

I still can't display correctly my legend

when i follow this

```
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(extent_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

  var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return h - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.8);

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return h - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
  .text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });
```

Legend is displayed first then map appears and overwrites it

I'd like to have map and legend displayed at the same time and legend displayed on the right-bottom corner of the map (where blank space is located)

I read a lot about z-index so i tried many things on the css part of my .legend but can't figure it out

[Here's my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SkEQjiAk0GaagmfcIw1?p=preview)

Thank you so much for your help and for explaining to me what my mistakes are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You place each element individually. I would not recommend that. You already use a `<g>` element to group the entries. So you could attach the positioning to that element.

With that being said: Your x-positioning is currently to 50. Use something which moves the boxes to the right like `w- 120`.

Implementing both yields:

```
var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(extent_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr( 'transform', function(d,i) {
    return 'translate( ' + (w - 120) + ' ' + (h - (i*ls_h) - ls_h) + ' )' 
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", -20 )
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", -4 )
  .text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback ^^ appreciate it. I don't get your "First..." , if i copy/paste your code, legend is displayed first. Mind modifying the plunker cause i still don't get it . Thank you so much

Comment: @MFAMOROCCO Regarding my first point: You create a group to hold both rectangle and text for each entry in the legend. In your code you position the rectangle and the text individually, which is not necessary as you can position the whole group.

Comment: Regarding the "displayed first" issue. If you want to display map and legend at the same time, move the legend creation inside the `.json()` callback, which paints your map. Btw modifying your plunker makes no sense as the map is not displayed there anyways.

Comment: U made my day. Thank you so much

Comment: Dear sirko,
seems it's not working anymore
i even posted a new question regarding this
in fact, my legend rectangles don't display the correct colors
i looked for it on different tutorials like  this one :    http://bl.ocks.org/jadiehm/raw/af4a00140c213dfbc4e6/
as you can see legend is incorrect
thank you so much for your help